# Kotlin: How to run a function with delay using extension function

Tags: android, kotlin, postdelayed

I'm trying to figure out how to use an extension function to run any method with a delay, but can't seem to figure it out.

I am trying something like below where I have a function and I want a handler to delay the execution by a certain timeInterval:

```
functionX().withDelay(500)
functionY().withDelay(500)

private fun Unit.withDelay(delay: Int) {
  Handler().postDelayed( {this} , delay)}

private fun Handler.postDelayed(function: () -> Any, delay: Int) {
  this.postDelayed(function, delay)}
```

Anyone?

Answer (score 7):

Another approach would be to declare a top-level (i.e. global) function like this:

```
fun withDelay(delay : Long, block : () -> Unit) {
    Handler().postDelayed(Runnable(block), delay)
}
```

Then you can call it, from anywhere, like this:

```
withDelay(500) { functionX() }
```

Comment: How we can do this with the cancel anytime in between delay timing?

Answer (score 6):

You should put the extension on the function type, not `Unit`:

```
fun functionX() {}
fun functionY() {}

private fun (() -> Any).withDelay(delay: Int) {
     Handler().postDelayed(this , delay)
}
```

Usage:

```
::functionX.withDelay(500)
::functionY.withDelay(500)
```

Here, `::functionX` is a [reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#function-references) to the global function called `functionX`.

Answer (score 2):

Or I like this version too:

Wrap whatever code block you want to be executed within { ... }

```
{ invokeSomeMethodHere() }.withDelay()
```

And have an extension function that invokes the Runnable after a certain delay:

```
fun <R> (() -> R).withDelay(delay: Long = 250L) {

    Handler().postDelayed({ this.invoke() }, delay)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing!

Comment: It has one issue though which I found out today. If you use it inside a callback, it doesn't work unless you add a `;` in previous statement because it considers previous line as part of the expression on which it is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can declare your global variables like:

```
private var handler: Handler = Handler()
private lateinit var runnableNewUrlBackground: Runnable
```

And also declare the function as global

```
init {
    runnableNewUrlBackground = Runnable {
        // Your function code here
        myCustomFun();
    }
}
```

Then, when you want to call this, just use:

```
handler.postDelayed(runnableNewUrlBackground, YOUR_DESIRED_TIME)
```